# Is there a solution that my box Y value increase or decrease its height value after "hitting" the wall?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

The base idea is simple: 
         I have a box, and it is changing its position by its WIDTH every x seconds (controlled by the "tick" value), and also when it hits the side of the screen it changes the direction. If it hits the right side of the screen the Y value incremented by the box HEIGHT value, if it hits the left side, then the Y value is decreased.

My problem is that after my box hits the wall, it is increases its Y value multiple times before changing direction. I want it to change 1 time and then go to the other direction.

I tried to change the box X value by extracting or adding 1 from/to it so there is a gap between the wall and box; so the IF statement will be false until the next frame and it will not increment the Y value, and the box have time to change direction and move to the other direction. This solution kinda worked but the box still jumped twice as high or low, and not exactly 1 HEIGHT.
I also tried a bunch of things too but this was the best I could come up with :/

Here is the sample code, I added a grid, so you can see exactly what my problem is.[HERE IS A PICTURE OF IT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfpuC.png)

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

WIN_W, WIN_H = 200, 500
FPS = 60

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_W, WIN_H))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# rect pos, dimensions
rct_x, rct_y = 100, 80
rct_w, rct_h = 20, 10

ct = 0
tick = .5
direction = True

run = True
while run:
    dt = clock.tick(FPS) / 1000
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    rct = pygame.Rect((rct_x, rct_y), (rct_w, rct_h))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 50, 50), rct)

    # grid for better viualisation
    for row in range(50):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (50, 100, 50), pygame.Rect((0, row * 10), (WIN_W-1, 1)), 1)
        for col in range(35):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (50, 100, 50), pygame.Rect((col * 20, 0), (1, WIN_H)), 1)

    # if rect Xpos + WIDTH greater than SCREEN WIDTH
    if rct_x + rct_w >= WIN_W:
        # increase rect Ypos by its HEIGHT
        rct_y += rct_h
        direction = False
    # if rect Xpos less than 0
    elif rct_x <= 0:
        # decease rect Ypos by its HEIGHT
        rct_y -= rct_h
        direction = True

    ct += dt
    if ct >= tick:
        ct = 0

        if direction:
            # move rect right if direction true
            rct_x += rct_w
        else:
            # move rect left if direction false
            rct_x -= rct_w

    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do all the movement only `if ct >= tick:`. If the object moves in y then it is not allowed to move in x. Add a variable `move_x`, which states  if the objects is allowed to be moved in x.
The object moved down once `if direction == True and rct_x + rct_w >= WIN_W` 
and it moves up once `if direction == False and rct_x <= 0:`

```py
while run:
    # [...]

    ct += dt
    if ct >= tick:
        ct = 0
        move_x = True

        # if rect Xpos + WIDTH greater than SCREEN WIDTH
        if direction == True and rct_x + rct_w >= WIN_W:
            # increase rect Ypos by its HEIGHT
            rct_y += rct_h
            direction = False
            move_x = False

        # if rect Xpos less than 0
        elif direction == False and rct_x <= 0:
            # decease rect Ypos by its HEIGHT
            rct_y -= rct_h
            direction = True 
            move_x = False   

        if move_x:
            if direction:
                # move rect right if direction true
                rct_x += rct_w
            else:
                # move rect left if direction false
                rct_x -= rct_w
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make `ct = tick` when it collides with the wall but this would make it move really quick which is probably not what your after.

You could also move the collision inside the tick if statement so it only checks when its about to move, and it can only move left, right, up or down in that if statement

```
    ct += dt
if ct >= tick:
    ct = 0
    # if rect Xpos + WIDTH greater than SCREEN WIDTH
    if rct_x + rct_w >= WIN_W:
        if direction != "left":
            direction = "down"
    # if rect Xpos less than 0
    elif rct_x <= 0:
        if direction != "right":
            direction = "up"        

    if direction == "right":
        rct_x += rct_w
    elif direction == "left":
        rct_x -= rct_w
    elif direction == "down":
        rct_y += rct_h
        direction = "left"
    elif direction == "up":
        rct_y -= rct_h
        direction = "right"
```

Testing if was on the edge and then moving it left or right meant it was moving left or right every time, which is not what you want as you want it to also move up and down without moving left or right. So i changed direction to 4 directions so it can only move in one direction every tick. if it is on the edge, it will change direction to move up or down, then move, the next frame it will still be on the edge and move up or down, so i added `if direction != "left"` so it will only go down if its on the edge and moving right, which is what you want.

Comment: This works, but now its skipping a block. With the Y value change its changing the X too. :/ so the box now jumps its height, but instead jumping below its previous location now, it is jumping +1 block on the X value too.

Comment: @Cappi I tested it this time and it does what you want. I updated the answer above